# SourceMonitor-like tool to analyze iPhone / Objective-C Code

Tags: objective-c, code-analysis

Is there any tool like SourceMonitor to analyze Objective-C Source code?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with iphone static analyzer  ?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I already analyzed with Analyze. Architect asked me to look into a tool like SourceMonitor, which has some function like Drawing a graph explaining complexity etc analyzing Java code for example. Is there similar thing for Objective-C ?

Answer (score 1):

There is one built into Xcode 4. Try "Product" followed by "Analyze" in the menu bar. I believe it uses the Clang Static Analyzer. You'll need to use additional tools if you require further code metrics.

Comment: Yes. I have tried with Analyze that use Clang Static Analyzer